# sidekiq and rspec doesn't work after rails admin upgrade to 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq, rails-admin

rails 6 - ruby 2.7.5

I updated rails admin, my application still works, except for some tests and sidekiq jobs.
I got this error:

```
WARN: ActionView::Template::Error: couldn't find file 'rails_admin/filter-box' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/francois/app/assets/config
  /home/francois/app/assets/images
  /home/francois/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/francois/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rails_admin-3.1.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rails_admin-3.1.1/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rails_admin-3.1.1/vendor/assets/fonts
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rails_admin-3.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rails_admin-3.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/turbo-rails-1.3.2/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/nested_form-0.3.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actioncable-6.1.7/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activestorage-6.1.7/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionview-6.1.7/lib/assets/compiled
  /home/francois/node_modules
```

I tried to do in my app something that failed in test, and it works. So I think maybe rspec and sidekiq need some configuration, but I found nothing about it.

Comment: Hi, did you run `rails g rails_admin:install` as recommended by rails-admin when upgrading? If you were upgrading from 2.x you should check the differences between the old and new version (using https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/compare/v2.2.1...v3.1.1 for instance).

Comment: I've opened a bug report for this issue, which I also experienced: https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/issues/3597

Were you able to solve it yourself?

Comment: @mevius, sorry for the delay, no I wasn't able to solve it

Comment: @Goulven yes I did follow the upgrading guide